# How to access groupby objects and add respective total in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with master_id and total as shown below

```
$scope.array = [{
  "master_id": {
       "id": 1    
  },
  "total" :50
},
{
  "master_id": {
       "id": 2    
  },
  "total":100
},
{
  "master_id": {
       "id": 1    
  },
  "total":150
},
{
  "master_id": {
       "id": 3    
  },
  "total":50
},
{
  "master_id": {
       "id": 2    
  },
  "total":200
}]
```

I am trying to add up the respective total based on master_id.id and push to another array. I tried to solve it but couldn't able to.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: *"I tried to solve it"* . The whole idea behind this site is for you to post the code you tried that isn't working as expected. This isn't a free code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create such array. Something like the snippet below.

Notice how it starts with an empty array, tries to find existing object on each iteration, if found, it will add up the `total`, otherwise, it will push a new object that has the `total` and `master_id` (or can just push `obj` directly)

```js
let arr = [{
    "master_id": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "total": 50
  },
  {
    "master_id": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "total": 100
  },
  {
    "master_id": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "total": 150
  },
  {
    "master_id": {
      "id": 3
    },
    "total": 50
  },
  {
    "master_id": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "total": 200
  }
]

let res = arr.reduce((myarr, obj) => {
  let exist = myarr.filter(t => t.master_id.id === obj.master_id.id)[0]
  if (exist) {
    exist.total += obj.total
  } else {
    myarr.push({
      "master_id": {
        "id": obj.master_id.id
      },
      total: obj.total
    })
  }
  return myarr
}, [])

console.log(res)
```